# bash remove the same in file

Tags: string, bash, shell

I have one issue with getting number different strings.

I have two files, for example :

file1 :

> aaa1
>
> aaa4
>
> bbb3
>
> ccc2

and

file2:

> bbb3
>
> ccc2
>
> aaa4

How from this get value 1 (in this case aaa1 string reason)?

I have one query but it calculates not only different strings, them also takes into account the order of the rows.

```
diff file1 file2 | grep "<" | wc -l
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grep -v -c` with other options as this:

```
grep -cvwFf file2 file1
1
```

Options used are:

```
-c - get the count of matches
-v - invert matches
-w - full word match (to avoid partial matches)
-F - fixed string match
-f - Use a file for matching patterns
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your requirements, sorting the files prior to the diff is a quick solution:

```
sort file1 > file1.sorted
sort file2 > file2.sorted
diff file1.sorted file2.sorted | egrep "[<>]" | wc -l
```